# bash array working in command prompt but not working when executing as ksh

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I am execution following .sh file in solaris box its not working but if i execute as command line, its working

```
bash-3.00$ ksh test.sh 
ksh test.sh 
test.sh[3]: syntax error at line 3 : `(' unexpected
```

**test.sh** is (not working)

```
#!/bin/ksh 
x1=`grep -i "\abc" /UC/*.*` 
x=($(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"))
```

**Manual Execution:** (working fine)

```
bash-3.00$ x=($(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"))
x=($(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"))
echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"
bash-3.00$ echo ${x[0]}
echo ${x[0]}
GOOD Boy
bash-3.00$
```

**Solaris Verison:**

> GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)

Comment: [tag:ksh] != [tag:bash]. Try running `bash test.sh`

Comment: Can you echo what you `x1` is? Guessing quoting `"$(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]")"` might help. Also, you should put [tag:ksh] as a tag rather than [tag:powershell]

Comment: x1 is grep results having some matched sentences

Comment: Right, but it's clearly trying to execute some `(` or other character, which is going to be specific to whatever `x1` actually is. So would help if you echoed it.

Comment: <MSCRI><![CDATA[abc></MSCRI> <MSCRI><![CDATA]></MSCRI> </MSCRI>></MSCRI>

Comment: ...'ya know, the Right Way to do this would involve an XML-aware parser (either something built for use from bash such as xmlstarlet, or a language more amenable to the purpose).

Comment: Why are you trying to use ksh to run a bash script?  They are different shells with different syntax for creating arrays.

Comment: Use `#!/bin/bash` as shebang.

Comment: My C++ compiler doesn't like my old PL/1 code, either... If a program is written in language X, then there should be no expectation that compilers/interpreters for language Y should "do the right thing" with that code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ksh (there's more than one) in this case is the old Solaris `ksh88` as `*(/usr)/bin/ksh`, which was the default `ksh` until (and including) Solaris 10.

AT&T open-sourced `ksh93` back in 2002 or so, which was adopted later into linux and various OpenSolaris derivatives.

`ksh93` and bash are quite close, and their developers have kept in touch and contributed to the POSIX shell standardisation effort.

The array assignment `x=( ... )` is supported in both ksh93 and bash, not in `ksh88`, where it results in the above syntax error.

> *how to solve this problem in ksh88 -- @logan*
>
> In ksh88 you can try:
>
> ```
> set -A x $(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]")
> ```

Finally, there have been alternative implementations like mksh and the commercial MKS.  I think the latter may actually share some code with the originals ksh88 from the AT&T Toolchest in the '80s.  The [MirBSD Korn shell](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm), or `mksh` is the successor of the abandoned `pdksh` project.

Comment: @logan Short answer: preferably not.  `ksh88` does still support numeric arrays, but you need to declare and set them with `set -A Array arg1 arg2 ...` (arg<n> optional).  After that you can set individual elements with `Array[n]="arg"`.  The number of elements in an array is limit to just over a thousand.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work under `ksh`. Run it using `bash`:

```
bash test.sh
```

Comment: Better yet, change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` (or wherever it's installed on Solaris, `/opt/public/secret/xpg4/compat/bash`?)

Comment: Can you explain the "this won't work under ksh" bit?

Comment: @broslow bash is not ksh. Some commands might work in both, but not all. You wouldn't expect perl to work if you ran it through the python interpreter. What is there to explain?

Comment: @kevin I'm not saying they don't have differences, but [tag:bash] and [tag:ksh] both derive from the bourne shell and syntactically I don't see why this won't work in [tag:ksh]

Comment: arrays aren't part of the Bourne shell specification, though. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html  However, it seems that newer ksh versions might have also started supporting the same extension.